# Have jQueryUI dialogbox display a div from a separate page (and pass php variables)

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

I've gotten used to using the jQueryUI dialogbox wherein I call it via `var $dialog = $('#repdia')`. I place the div (shown below) on the bottom most part of the page. That was fine when I only had 1 dialogbox to pop out. I'm currently working on different dialogboxes from a single page and it just looks to stacked when I put 3 divs at the bottom to handle 3 different dialogboxes. Is there a way for the widget to pull up the div from a separate page?

```
<div id="repdia" title="Compose reply">
<form action="<?echo $currURL;?>" method="post">
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col width="10%" />
        <col width="90%" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="bol">To:</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="recipient" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="bol">Subject:</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subject" maxlength="60" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <p><textarea name="content"></textarea>
        </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <span class="diabut">
        <input name="sendmsg" type="hidden" value="go" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send message" />&nbsp;<button id="clodia">Cancel</button></span>
       </td> 
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

This is the javascript part:

```
$(function() {
    var $dialog = $('#repdia').load("dialogtest.php")
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 360,
                draggable: true
            })

    $('.repope').click(function (e) {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#clodia').click( function() {
        $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], input[type=hidden], textarea").val("");
        $dialog.dialog("close");
        return false;
    });
});
```

[UPDATE]

Okay, so I managed to load the page. Follow up questions would be:

1. How do I pass php variables to the dialogbox? I have extracted rows from a MySQL database and I would need to pass them to the dialogbox. (ie. $r_username, $r_subject, etc)
2. How do I set the size of the dialogbox accordingly? I'm planning to use just one javascript code which will load different parts of `dialogtest.php` depending on which selector they click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an ajax request with [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to get the div content from another page before displaying it.

```
$('#repdia').load("path/to/other/page", function()
{ 
    $('#repdia').dialog(); 
});
```

Here's an example with your updated script using GET parameters in the load method. Both do the same thing; pass variables to your php script.

```
// using query string parameters
var $dialog = $('#repdia').load("dialogtest.php?param1=a&param2=b")
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    height: 360,
                    draggable: true
                });

// using the data parameter
var $dialog = $('#repdia').load("dialogtest.php", {param1: "a", param2: "b"})
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    height: 360,
                    draggable: true
                });
```

If you want to use POST, you can use the [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method.

```
$.post("dialogtest.php", {param1: "a", param2: "b"}, function(data) {
    $('#repdia').html(data)
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    height: 360,
                    draggable: true
                });
});
```

Comment: Yes. I just need it to get the whole div with id `repdia`. I might be leaning towards putting all dialogbox divs in one page.

Comment: Yes, but you could load a "partial" page that only includes the markup you need for the dialog.

Comment: @jrummell, is there a way for you to pass either $_get or $_post data to the dialogbox you're opening?

Comment: Sure, you can append get parameters to your url in the .load() method, or you can provide them in the data parameter. See http://api.jquery.com/load/.

Comment: Thanks, @jrummel. I've included my javascript to the question up top. If I put the whole `repdia` div to, let's say, `dialogtest.php`, how can I make it show? I could use your suggestion in appending get parameters, but how about post contents? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for this! It was my fault not to place the `<script>` tags at the end of the page. Reason why the post values were empty. Again, thanks for taking the time to answer my questions. 'preciate it.

Comment: If I'm using `{param1: "<?=$firstname?>", param2: "<?=$lastname?>"}`, does this mean I cannot call the script from a `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dialogbox.js"></script>`? I'll have to really put the javascript code at the bottom of the page? It doesn't seem to be working if I just call it using src tags.

Comment: That's another question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412492/server-variables-and-the-js-file-is-it-possible

Comment: That's just too much work. I'll stick with internal js on this one. Thanks for the help, bud.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's load function allows you to load just page fragments. See their official API documentation on it here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#dialogContainer').load("path/to/other/page #repdia", function() { 
     $('#dialogContainer').dialog(); 
});
```

Comment: Just a follow up, would I be able to also pass $_post variables from the page I launched the dialogbox from?